# A weird Web 1.0 nazi site wants help. How to handle?

Tags: support, allowed-topics, users

https://superuser.com/users/1005157/mehdi-saada wants help with his nazi site national-naturalism [dot] org

- https://superuser.com/questions/1738894/how-to-get-a-base-font-size-on-my-screen-for-my-site-scales-up-to-higher-resolu
- https://superuser.com/questions/1829169/firefox-support-of-native-css-nesting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAy16.jpg

This sort of content is inappropriate to the site and I'd appreciate it if someone cleaned up this mess?

Comment: A 7 day suspension? Are you sure? Read some of the pages on that site.

Comment: We should learn from that other website with usergenerated content https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_Nazis quite a few good policy ideas there that could be used to improve SE sites.

Comment: That site reminds me of the bad old days, in more ways than one.

Answer (score 8):

While we *don't* want that sort of content here - but we don't police what people do off this site, and *unless* there's a clear interaction or reproduction of that content on the site, well its not our problem.

Where it *is*, we can deal with it in context but we're not going to suspend people for what's on their personal spaces outside SE perview.

Said content has been cleared up (partially for being off topic) and we've communicated our expectations both of topicality, and that folks are uncomfortable with some of this content leaking into the site via their questions.

Comment: `unless there's a clear interaction or reproduction of that content on the site` dude posted a link to a nazi website... Imagine being Jewish or LGBTQ+ on SU/SE (or any other site where posting a link to a nazi website gets you only a 7 day suspension and the person who reported the nazi gets threatened with a block for using the word that starts with s and means poop)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Posting a link to a nazi site is banworthy imho. We already have plenty of evidence what not banning them leads to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance

Comment: I'd like to believe 99.99% of folks have an intolerance to Nazi viewpoints, and I understand the point @Gantendo is making, yet unless the user's including their views in a question _(which has been deleted and I can't view)_, banning/suspending them isn't going to solve anything - a new account will be created by the user and the question asked leaving out the viewpoints. This applies to pretty much everything - I've come across questions where there's a strong possibility the question being asked is for malicious purposes, but with no clear indication. That's a slippery slope to go down